# how to create two adjacent table of same size using HTML?

Tags: html, xhtml

first table is having less number of rows where as another having more row. As both of them are adjacent to each other. without adding more empty rows in it and making use of nbsp. Is there any other tag or attribute which we can use.

Comment: Are you creating them dynamically?

Comment: Same size means height & width should be same?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the rows on each table to be the same height, you could put both tables around a div element with a set height and float left. A border effect will make it seem like they're the same height.

Try seeing how it looks with the table height as 100%. If that doesn't render well, give the table a set height and each tr's height as the table height / number of rows.